# I am thinking on going

Tags: prepositions, usage

Is it correct to say *I am thinking of going to the beach* or should I say *I am thinking on going to the beach?*

Comment: There are many odd sentences that can make sense given the appropriate context. 'Correctness' depends on what you're trying to say. What are you trying to say?

Comment: 'I am thinking on going to the beach' is not necessarily ungrammatical, as Lawrence implies, but 'I am considering leaving'  (ie deciding whether to, and quite possibly going to, leave)  = 'I am thinking **of** leaving'.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean you are considering that you will maybe go to the beach, the normal statement is

> I am thinking *of* going to the beach.

If you used *on* instead of *of* if would mean that you were thinking in the abstract about the concept of going to the beach, and even then it would be unusual.

You might say something like "I am thinking on the subject of death and forgiveness in the writings of J.K. Rowling", but even then the word "about" would be more usual than "on".